# How to fix the ClassNotFoundException in Android

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I have tried to implement TabHost on android for few days and I am stuck on one error. I deleted my core tabhost code, I still have same error. I think it is my manifest.xml. Base on my error msg, I look up the source manifest but I couldn't find it.

Error

`E/AndroidRuntime(32386): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.FragmentLayout" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.sysdisc.mobile.hangmessage-1.apk`

Code

```
public class AA extends FragmentActivity{
private ListView inboxList;
private ListView outboxList;
private ListView listView1;
private ListView listView2;
ProgressDialog dialog;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.pleaseWait));
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.loading);
    setContentView(R.layout.message_history_entire_layout);
    }
}
```

This is my xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <FragmentLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
           <ListView android:id="@+id/list1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
      </ListView>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/list2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>  
       </FragmentLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your

> project properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export >

Make sure `com.google.android.maps.jar` is selected.

Then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: So I followed your solution. still have same problem.... should I give you the manifest.xml?

Comment: No it's not a problem with the manifest. Make sure android private libraries is clicked. And any external jar you're using is clicked in Order and Export.

Comment: Also after you selected maps.jar and did a clean did your error message change?

Comment: Yes Yes  I did.
I just found out that the error  indicates setContentView(R.layout.message_history_entire_layout);

on my log : Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class FragmentLayout